# Как сделать не закрывающуюся программу на Java SE?

Tags: java

Нужно сделать что бы программа после запуска ожидала команд и после того как команда отработала она продолжала их ждать.

Comment: А как она будет получать команды?

Comment: @AGS17 Ну вообще через USB. Но я пока что делаю имитацию этого.

Comment: Она сама будет что-то мониторить или вы собираетесь посылать в вашу программу команды непосредственно?

Comment: @AGS17 после запуска она будет ждать команды от usb входа. Не я.

Comment: После обработки вернуться к ожиданию. Просто зациклить это. И тогда следующий Ваш вопрос будет "Как остановить проклятую программу?"

Comment: @Sergey ну для остановки можно придумать команду, или просто закрыть консоль ибо будет работать по виндой. Проблем не вижу

Comment: @AGS17 если я сделаю UI приложение то я же могу отслеживать запросы?

Comment: @Tsyklop что значит отслеживать? Если api позволяет, то подпишитесь на требуемый ивент, иначе можно зациклить как предложил Alex78191 и опрашивать самостоятельно. Только делайте это в другом потоке,иначе UI зависнет.

Answer (score 4):

Сделай обработку в цикле while(true) или напиши прогу с UI.
Можешь запускать задачу в новом потоке и [ждать от пользователя ввода символа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33440866/how-do-you-keep-the-console-from-closing-after-the-program-is-done).

Comment: в том и дело нужна консольная программа. Спасибо.

Comment: @Tsyklop вы решили проблему?

Comment: в принципе да. Всё таки буду делать UI.

Comment: @Tsyklop Чем вас не устроили остальные способы?

Comment: асинхронно пока что не нужно.

Comment: @Tsyklop Чем плох бесконечный цикл?

Comment: так я его и использую.

Comment: @Tsyklop Зачем тогда GUI,если программа и так не закроется?

Comment: тем что мне нужно открывать картинки и видео во весь экран. Я начал пробовать и такой возможности нет. Сейчас смотрю можно ли открыть GUI приложение на весь экран - тобишь скрыв сам таскбар в винде.